# Nuget consolidate vs update

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

In NuGet for Visual Studio 2015, what is the difference between **consolidate** and **update** actions? In both cases I select a specific version that I want to use in selected projects.

Comment: See https://artczernecki.wordpress.com/2015/09/08/consolidating-package-versions-with-visual-studio-2015-nuget-package-manager/

Comment: Question from my understanding is what is the difference between Installed and Consolidate tabs. They apparently offer the same view/help doing the same thing.

Comment: see also [why we need to consolidate packages with different versions?](//stackoverflow.com/q/70458434)

Answer (score 109):

The Update tab is geared to display packages which have updates available while the consolidation tab is geared to display discrepancies between projects where both consume the same nuget package but are targeting different versions.

Comment: Nuget [blog post about this feature](https://blog.nuget.org/20151118/nuget-3.3.html#consolidate)

Answer (score 20):

Sometimes the versions installed into projects within a solution can drift apart and it is necessary to consolidate the versions in use.

See https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-3.0-preview for more information.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [blog](http://ericphan.net/blog/2016/1/22/consolidating-nuget-package-versions), it simply makes it easier to update different versioned NuGet packages across your projects

Answer (score 1):

Consolidate has now been documented here: [NuGet Package Manager UI -> Consolidate tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui#consolidate-tab)

---

Tthanks to @kraigb to getting this into the official docs; reference: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/issues/498)

Comment: Link-only answers are considered to be of poor quality. Consider to make the answer actually answering the question without need to go elsewhere to find the answer.